# Rider - .editorconfig: File scoped namespaces not respected

Tags: resharper, rider, editorconfig

I'm using Rider 2021.3.3 (latest version), and when I have the latest .NET SDK on my machine (.NET 6).

Inside the `.editorconfig` file, I have added the following:

`csharp_namespace_body = file_scoped`

When I create a new project, it contains a file with a File-scoped namespace:

```
namespace ClassLibrary2;

public class Class1
{
}
```

If I change it to a block-scoped namespace and I run a cleanup, the file doesn't change but remains using the block-scoped namespace.

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Rider is configured to read settings from the .editorconfig file.
Changing the rules that specifies how much blank lines are required before a single line comment, this is respected.

```csharp_blank_lines_before_single_line_comment            = 1`

Any idea on what's going wrong?

Comment: Does it work with your `.editorconfig` in Visual Studio (just to doublecheck the correctness)? And does it work with the corresponding Rider setting (_File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | C# → Syntax Style → Code Body → Namespaces_)?

Comment: It seems it's related to a large solutions some targetting old .NET, new ones targetting .net core / net 6.

Comment: So does it work in the newer .NET 6 settings? If so, you can try to set `<LangVersion>latestMajor</LangVersion>` within `csproj` of the older projects - this will enable C# 10 support and therefore file-scoped namespaces

Comment: I know, but that;'s not what I'm looking for. I'm wondering why Rider doesn't respect the given settings in the `.editorconfig` file.

Comment: Ah wait, do you want to happen the refactoring from block- to file-scoped namespaces __automatically__? If yes, that doesn't seem to be possible right now - at least I never found out how. We decided to set the severity for this to _Warning_

Comment: Have you tried running `dotnet style` command after changes to `.editorconfig`? It should apply changes to the entire project or solution (I am pretty sure it all must be in .net 6 though).

Comment: How does that interact with Rider / ReSharper?