# Use dotnet format to switch to file-scoped namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, format

I'm trying to use the dotnet format command to convert a large C# solution to leverage [file-scoped namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces).

I've tried annotating my preference for these in the solution's .editorconfig with both

```
# from https://www.meziantou.net/updating-your-project-to-use-file-scoped-namespaces.htm
csharp_style_namespace_declarations=file_scoped:suggestion
```

and

```
# from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652548/rider-editorconfig-file-scoped-namespaces-not-respected
csharp_namespace_body = file_scoped
```

However, when I run `dotnet format My.sln` it makes some whitespace formatting fixes (e. g. removing trailing whitespace) but does not convert to file-scoped namespaces. Is this supposed to work? What am I missing?

I'm using `dotnet` 6.0.201 and I've also tried downloading an updated build of `dotnet-format` (7.0.321101+ec7537dd0645b35fc9057006639ca41e37d16348).

Answer (score 5):

One way to solve this is by increasing that `suggestion` to `error` or `warning`.

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:error
```

Then it will be picked up by `dotnet format`, as you were already doing.

```
dotnet format My.sln
```

---

Alternatively you can leave it to `suggestion`

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations=file_scoped:suggestion
```

and pass `--severity info` to `dotnet format`

```
dotnet format My.sln --severity info
```

---

By default `dotnet format` runs with `--severity warn`, which does apply the `.editorconfig` settings configured with the `warning` and `error` severity but not those with `suggestion`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-format#options) about `--severity`

> The minimum severity of diagnostics to fix. Allowed values are `info`, `warn` and `error`. The default value is `warn`.